# creating a stored procedure to return a list of airports lat and long

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Here's what I have so far but I can't get it to run properly. I keep getting an error that the syntax is incorrect ON FROM where it reads `FROM TBL_AIRPORT AIR`. But I can't figure out what is supposed to be there, or what to change so I can't run it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE SP_GETAIRPORTS
    @GEOLOCATION GEOGRAPHY = NULL,
    @ICAOCODE VARCHAR(10) = NULL,
    @IATACODE VARCHAR(4) = NULL,
    @COUNTRY_FK INT = NULL,
    @STRNAME VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL, 
    @STRCITY VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @INT_ELEVATION INT = NULL
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF

    SELECT 
        GEOLOCATION.LAT, GEOLOCATION.LONG, ICAOCODE, IATACODE, 
        STRNAME, STRCITY, COUNTRY.COUNTRYNAME, INT_ELEVATION 
    FROM 
        TBL_AIPORT AIR
    FROM 
        TBL_AIRPORT AIR
    JOIN 
        TBL_COUNTRY C ON C.COUNTRY_ID = AIR.COUNTRY_FK
    WHERE 
        GEOLOCATION.LAT <> 0 OR GEOLOCATION.LONG <> 0
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    -- .....
END CATCH
```

Comment: That's because you have redundant 'FROM TBL_AIRPORT AIR'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite your `select` clause, because you used 'TBL_AIRPORT' table twice  with same key word 'FROM' and also properly write begin and commit transactions syntax.

```
SELECT 
    GEOLOCATION.LAT, GEOLOCATION.LONG, ICAOCODE, IATACODE, STRNAME,   
    STRCITY, COUNTRY.COUNTRYNAME, INT_ELEVATION 
FROM 
    TBL_AIRPORT AIR
JOIN 
    TBL_COUNTRY C ON C.COUNTRY_ID = AIR.COUNTRY_FK
WHERE 
    GEOLOCATION.LAT <> 0 OR GEOLOCATION.LONG <> 0
```

Comment: Yes! So simple. And it was driving me nuts. Thank you

Comment: its now not returning the geolocation.lat or geolocation.long as anything. I get an error, could not find property of field for 'Lat' Microsoft.Sql.serverttype.....

Comment: LAT and LONG presented in which table..?

Comment: Figured it out. It had to be written as SELECT GEOLOCATION.Lat instead of GEOLOCATION.LAT. IT was a case sensitive field!